# Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value on flutter FCM

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

whenever the app start, it always give this warning. For now, it doesnt give any bug, but I'm afraid if it will turn into some bugs later on.
This is the error

```
E/flutter (11083): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (11083): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.registerBackgroundMessageHandler (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_messaging.dart:180:53)
E/flutter (11083): #1      FirebaseMessagingPlatform.onBackgroundMessage= (package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_messaging.dart:102:16)
E/flutter (11083): #2      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage (package:firebase_messaging/src/messaging.dart:85:31)
E/flutter (11083): #3      messageHandler (package:sobatku/main.dart:249:21)
E/flutter (11083): <asynchronous suspension>
```

And I already put the message handler outside of `main` function

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  messageHandler();
  runApp(App());
}
```

MessageHandler

```
Future<void> messageHandler() async {

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance
      .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage event) {
    LocalNotification.showNotification(event);
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((message) => _messageHandler(message));
}
```

The main.dart structure

[image]

Comment: @JahnE. I tried that but it still give me that warning

Comment: Did you exactly follow the docs, because currently your structure looks different?   https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages

Comment: Ah yeah, looks like I miss something. Thank you.